# what does the "makefile" mean in the Makefile "kaodv.o: $(KOBJS) Makefile"

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I have a makefile. In the file there are some words :

`kaodv.o: $(KOBJS) Makefile
     $(LD) -r $(KOBJS) -o $@`

I do not known the "makefile" mean in these words. Can some body help me?

Answer (score 2):

That is listing the makefile as a prerequisite for the `kaodv.o` object file.

So that if the makefile changes the object file will be rebuilt. This is the same as how the files in `$(KOBJS)` (which is a slightly odd name for that variable in this context) means.

This is likely an attempt to get `kaodv.o` to rebuild for flag changes made to the makefile. This will do that but will also recompile for any other changes. Unfortunately a more fine-grained `flags-only` approach requires a bit more work.

Answer (score 0):

It means that execute the rules for building `kaodv.o` if `Makefile` has changed.

This is there, most likely, to make sure that if compiler flags in `Makefile` are changed, the `.o` file is rebuilt.